# наследование бинов в Spring

Tags: java, spring

Я попытался создать 2 бина :

```
@Component class A{...}

@Component class B extends A{...}
```

но при *autowire*-инге вылетает ошибка

> No qualifying bean of type is define: expected single matching bean bu found 2

Что мне делать, если надо унаследовать один бин от другого?

Comment: Унаследованный класс уже аннотирован, так как унаследвоан от соответствующего, разве нет? autowirингом классы не отмечаются

Comment: @arturk не понял вопроса

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А как Спринг должен понять, в каком случае какой бин использовать? Либо дайте бинам имена и внедряйте конкретный при помощи `@Qualifier`:

```
@Component("a") class A{...}

@Component("b") class B extends A{...}

@Autowired @Qualifier("b") A b;
@Autowired @Qualifier("a") A a;

A a1 = appContext.getBean("a");
A b1 = appContext.getBean("b");
```

либо откажитесь от `@Autowired` и конфигурируйте зависимости вручную через сеттеры.

Comment: а если я захочу достать бин из контекста методом getBean ? там вроде нельзя qualifier задавать

Comment: чтобы вытаскивать через `getBean()` (хотя на  99% вы можете без этого обойтись), задайте бинам  имя через `@Component("a")` и `@Component("b")`.

Comment: Дополнил пример в ответе.